# Помогите разъяснить запятые в предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, приложение

Награждается Ильина Ника, ученица 3 класса школы № 3 за отличную учёбу и хорошее поведение.

Answer (score 3):

Нужно поставить ещё одну запятую:

*Награждается Ильина Ника, **ученица 3 класса школы № 3,** за хорошую учёбу и примерное поведение.*

> **5. Обособляется** приложение, стоящее после имени собственного: *Чемодан внесли кучер Селифан, **низенький человек в тулупчике,** и лакей Петрушка, **малый лет тридцати в подержанном сюртуке*** (Г.); *Сергей Никанорыч, **буфетчик,** налил пять стаканов чаю* (Ч.); *Безродный человек Маркуша, **дворник,** сидя на полу, строгал палочки и планки для птичьих клеток* (М. Г.).

Источник: [Обособленные приложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111) (справочник Розенталя).

Answer (score 0):

> Правило про согласованные определения: определительный оборот,
> относящийся к существительному, выделяют запятыми только если он стоит
> после существительного, а определение, относящееся к личному
> местоимению, выделяют всегда, вне зависимости от его места в
> предложении.

Значит запятые должны быть после слова "Ника" и "№ 3":
Награждается Ильина Ника, ученица 3 класса школы № 3, за отличную учёбу и хорошее поведение.

Comment: Василий, приветствую Вас на этом сайте! Отрадно видеть новых участников, отвечающих на вопросы, особенно если их ответы чего-то стоят. Позволю себе дать несколько советов. Я постоянно призываю всех голосовать за все полезные вопросы и ответы, отмечайте хотя бы те вопросы, на которые отвечаете (у Вас 28 ответов и всего один голос). Относитесь к своим ответам более педантично, обращайте внимание на собственную пунктуацию и оформление (например, в этом ответе не хватает запятой после "значит",  а также Вы приводите цитату, которая на самом деле не является таковой). Спасибо.

Comment: Вижу уже два голоса :))  Также на сайте принято давать ссылки на те источники, которыми Вы руководствуетесь.

Comment: Понял, учту, спасибо. P.S. Мои основные источники - учебники для средней школы 60-х годов прошлого века, актуализированные 40-летним опытом писания статей и монографий. Но постараюсь искать публикации, актуальные для сегодняшних читателей.

Comment: Если не из Интернета, можно просто написать, откуда оно. Если автор довольно известен, можно просто его указать. А примеры лучше курсивом оформлять.

Comment: Василий, вы, вероятно, специалист в какой-то научной области?  А не намекнете, в какой именно?  По вашим ответам трудно было догадаться, кто вы, так что вы меня заинтриговали.

Comment: @Sharon Ихтиоэтолог, поведением рыб занимаюсь.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ.  К людям, занимающимся наукой и к их мнению, я отношусь с особым уважением.